# What's the relation between ss:sp and extended BIOS(int 0x13, ah = 0x42)?

Tags: assembly, bootloader

If I don't initialized the the ss and sp or initialize correctly(for example ss:sp = 0xA000:0x0000), the code as below picture will not jump correctly.

[boot sector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Ktk.png)

I want to copy 244 sectors from disk to memory by using extended BIOS interrupts(int 0x13, ah = 0x42, LBA).

Comment: Presumably on the BIOS you're testing with, the initial `ss:sp` is in the region of memory you're loading sectors into.  Setting SS:SP yourself before writing to memory outside the 512 bytes starting at linear address 7C00 is done to make sure you aren't overwriting your own stack memory, or having stack memory overwrite your data.

Comment: Could I understand like that, the BIOS interrupts maybe use the ss:sp to achieve its own function in an unsafe way? Because BIOS has its own memory region.

Comment: Unsafe?  Your own `int 0x13` pushes a CS:IP return address (and other stuff) onto your stack at SS:SP.  So even if the BIOS changed to its own stack somewhere else, returning to the caller would still break after the BIOS restored your SS:SP to do an `iret`.  (Unless it actually copied the return address off the stack; `iret` can restore a different SS:SP as well as a CS:IP so it would be possible, but I don't think that's what most BIOSes would do.)

Comment: Thx, you are right. I forgot that the interrupt will push cs:ip and other stuff to the stack.

Comment: "`iret` can restore a different SS:SP as well as a CS:IP" Not in Real 86 Mode, it only ever pops IP, CS, and FL off the current stack.